# Is this a correct Interlocked synchronization design?

Tags: c#, synchronization, multithreading, locking, interlocked

I have a system that takes Samples.  I have multiple client threads in the application that are interested in these Samples, but the actual process of taking a Sample can only occur in one context.  It's fast enough that it's okay for it to block the calling process until Sampling is done, but slow enough that I don't want multiple threads piling up requests.  I came up with this design (stripped down to minimal details):

```
public class Sample
{
    private static Sample _lastSample;
    private static int _isSampling;

    public static Sample TakeSample(AutomationManager automation)
    {
        //Only start sampling if not already sampling in some other context
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isSampling, 0, 1) == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Sample sample = new Sample();
                sample.PerformSampling(automation);
                _lastSample = sample;
            }
            finally
            {
                //We're done sampling
                _isSampling = 0;
            }
        }

        return _lastSample;
    }

    private void PerformSampling(AutomationManager automation)
    {
        //Lots of stuff going on that shouldn't be run in more than one context at the same time
    }
}
```

Is this safe for use in the scenario I described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it looks safe because `int` is an atomic type here. But I would still advice replacing

```
private static int _isSampling;
```

with

```
private static object _samplingLock = new object();
```

and use :

```
lock(_samplingLock)
{
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.PerformSampling(automation);
   _lastSample = sample;
}
```

Simply because it is the recommended pattern and also makes sure all access to _lastSample is treated correctly.

NB: I would expect comparable speed, lock uses the managed Monitor class that uses Interlocked internally.

**Edit:**

I missed the back-off aspect, here is another version :

```
   if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_samplingLock))
   {
     try
     {
         .... // sample stuff
     }
     finally
     {
          System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_samplingLock);
     }
   }
```

Comment: The TryEnter is probably better from a maintenance perspective, as most likely more people will be familiar with Monitor.TryEnter than with Interlocked.CompareExchange.  I'm not too worried about overhead in this case, as I'm only taking samples a few times per second.  When it does actually perform sampling, the overhead of the sampling process itself will be quite a bit more than the locking primitive, I'm sure.

Comment: I like the Monitor.TryEnter, but shouldnt we be using the ReaderWriterLockSlim these days??

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim_members.aspx

Comment: @Mike_g : No, only when the situation calls for it. I don't see that here.

Comment: Okay, it's using TryEnter now; so much for the 'clever' solution. :)  On a side note, I can't edit the post, but the correct method is Monitor.Exit(_samplingLock).

Comment: Interlocked.CompareExchange() is very efficient than the given solution. You just changed what he asked.

Comment: @SimpleFellow - not clear what you mean. "efficient" has been dealt with here, it's about the general practice of locking a resource like _lastSample .

Comment: isn't Interlocked.CompareExchange() is times faster than Monitor.TryEnter()/Exit()?     (Reference: http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/02/why-autoresetevent-is-slow-and-how-to.html)

Comment: It is faster, but will you notice that here? Don't micro-optimize at the cost of readability.

Answer (score -1):

I usually declare a volatile bool and do something like:

```
private volatile bool _isBusy;
private static Sample _lastSample;

private Sample DoSomething()
{
     lock(_lastSample)
     {
       if(_isBusy)
          return _lastSample;
       _isBusy = true;
     }

     try
     {
       _lastSample = new sameple//do something
     }
     finally
     {
        lock(_lastSample)
        {
           _isBusy = false;
        }
     }
     return _lastSample;
}
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to declare the bool volatile if you're only using it inside a lock anyway. Besides, it's a very bad practice to lock on a mutable field. In your sample, it's possible two lock blocks are entered at the same time. When you lock on a mutable field I would expect a detailed comment about why it couldn't hurt (that much) if two (or maybe even more) threads entered a lock block simultaneously.